# Luhn Algorithm sorting out

Tags: c#, boolean

I am sorting this code:

```
bool checkLuhn(const string& cardNo) 
{ 
    int nDigits = cardNo.length(); 

    int nSum = 0, isSecond = false; 
    for (int i = nDigits - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 

        int d = cardNo[i] - '0'; 

        if (isSecond == true) 
            d = d * 2; 

        nSum += d / 10; 
        nSum += d % 10; 

        isSecond = !isSecond; 
    } 
    return (nSum % 10 == 0); 
}
```

There is one mystery what i do not know. Have googled, but still mystery.

That code:

```
if (isSecond == true) 
d = d * 2;
```

Where on the code program detects is it splitable with 2? I understand if it's not splitable with 2, program multiply it with 2.

I understand operational principle of the program, but there must be some method or something which tells program what is that isSecond. Help me guys.

Comment: This is what does it: `isSecond = !isSecond;`.

Comment: `isSecond` is set to `false` before the `for` statement and its value is changed inside of it (*i.e.* `isSecond = !isSecond`).

Comment: Read up on the algorithm (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm). The program doubles the value of "every second digit" during the calculation

Comment: also, please give credit to the site from where you get the code as well (hyperlink or something) [Luhn algorithm from GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/luhn-algorithm/)

Comment: Thank for comments!

Yes i took it from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/luhn-algorithm/.

@ScottHunter I know Luhn 100% except that ```isSecond = !isSecond;``` . How it checks is it splitable with 2? I understand that when it's not splitable with 2, program multiply it with 2 like in this ```d = d * 2; ``` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i understand it.

Before the for loop isSecond is false because first ordernumber is (0). Then this `isSecond = !isSecond;` change false to true. Then it's turn of the second ordernumber (1) and `isSecond = true;` so method multiplies it with 2. And then it goes false again and not multiplies number 2. Then it goes true and multiply number 3.

What a brain-teaser :D